# Visualforce renderAs PDF page size error

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf, renderas, size

I need to render a small pdf page, height = 15mm and width = 30 mm.
I have developed a VF page but I am not able to get the required page size.

I am getting the error '**Page style attributes result in invalid (negative) page size.**'

Below is my code:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="Account" standardStylesheets="false" cache="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false"  >
    <head>
        <style type = "text/css">
            @page { 
                size: landscape;
                size:15mm 30mm!important;
            }   
        </style>
    </head>

    <apex:outputText value="test"></apex:outputText>

</apex:page>
```

I can't figure out the CSS to apply.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Page style attributes result in invalid (negative) page size.  It means you are defining the page size which is not acceptable for rendering a page as pdf. It expects at least  **size:25.5mm 25.5mm!important;** or greater than that.

> Here, the first parameter is the width of the page and the second one
>   is the height of the page.

The page will look like this:- 
[image: pdf]

Try below code, it will give you a page size of 25.5mm square:-

```
    <apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="Account" standardStylesheets="false" cache="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false"  >
    <head>
        <style type = "text/css">
            @page { 
                size: landscape;
                size:25.5mm 25.5mm!important;
            }   
        </style>
    </head>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks. Any documentation where it says size should be at least 25.5mm x 25.5mm?

Comment: I could not find any but you can try.. It will give you the error. I just analysed it by trY and error.